# Why would clearFocus() and setVisibility() have no effect?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an EditText view lose focus, dismiss the keyboard and become invisible. Debugging shows that the code is being executed and the search_view and view objects are referencing the same object. None of the methods being called seem to have an effect though.

```
OnKeyListener enter_pressed = new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View view, int key_code, KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch ( key_code ) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
            view.clearFocus();
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
            view.setVisibility(0);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Also, strangely, the code falls through to the default case, even past the return statement. Adding a break after the return throw a warning in Eclipse about unreachable code, which I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view.setVisibility(0) is the same as view.setVisibility(View.VISIBILE)  what you want is View.INVISIBLE or View.GONE (4 or 8 respectively).

as for the pass through, when debugging what is the value of key_code?  maybe its not KEYCODE_ENTER which is 66

for hiding the keyboard i like:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Perhaps I was mistaken, it no longer falls through.
View.VISIBLE != VISIBLE helps a lot.